# Multiple schemes when testing

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I have multiple schemes set up in Xcode (Dev/Staging/Production). Each of these has a different module name, e.g. for staging the app is called MyApp_dev, but in production it's just called MyApp. I have written unit/UI tests that I've run using the staging environment by adding @testable to MyApp_dev. However, when I build the code for production, the MyApp module will no longer be available. If I run the tests in the staging environment but build for production, will this cause problems?

Comment: This is a pretty non-standard approach as far as I know, so answering this question would require some more details on what the differences are for you between the schemes, environments, & builds.  It might also help if you outlines what problems you expect to happen.

Comment: @nhgrif What's the standard approach for multiple environments with tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this will not cause problems. Assuming that "build the code for production" means archiving and distributing, building the code for production will not run the tests, or even build them. This approach is fine.

You can enable/disable building and/or testing (and more) in the scheme editor window. Each scheme you define is very customizable, so take some time to look through all the settings.